# Ошибка. 2 Заголовочных файла

Tags: c++

Почему происходят ошибки. 
1. C4430 Отсутствует спецификатор типа — предполагается int. Примечание: C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию. 
2. C2146 Синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствует «;» перед идентификатором «a»

Как это исправить? 
Как мне сделать чтобы заголовок A включал в себя B. 
И наоборот B включал заголовок A?

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header_A.h"
#include "Header_B.h"

A a;
B b;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Header_A.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Header_B.h"

extern B b;

struct A {
};
```

Header_B.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Header_A.h"

extern A a;

struct B {
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проделайте работу препросессора, разверните исходник и все заголовки в один файл.
и даже не обязательно делать это вручную.

```bsh
g++ -E Source.cpp
```

```cpp
# 1 "Source.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "Source.cpp"
# 1 "Header_A.h" 1

# 1 "Header_B.h" 1



extern A a;

struct B {
};
# 3 "Header_A.h" 2

extern B b;

struct A {
};
# 2 "Source.cpp" 2


A a;
B b;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

В итоге получается, что на момент объявления

```cpp
extern A a;
```

сам тип `A` еще не объявлен. добавьте перед ним

```cpp
struct A;
```

При этом сами перекрестные инклюды не так уж и нужны, достаточно того, что они есть в `Source.cpp` перед определениями `a` и `b`.

Comment: Теперь понял спасибо!